# Why are PIL and its Image module capitalized?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pep8

[PEP8 standard is for modules to be lower-case](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

PIL being a top-level module in all caps isn't so bad, but to [name a module Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) and then have a class in that module called Image seems unnecessarily confusing.

Why was it done this way?

Comment: Because not everyone cares about / agrees on standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL predates PEP8 by about 5 or 6 years

From the Pillow (the maintained fork) LICENSE:

```
The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is

    Copyright © 1997-2011 by Secret Labs AB
    Copyright © 1995-2011 by Fredrik Lundh
```

And PEP8:

```
PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code

Author:
    Guido van Rossum <guido at python.org>, Barry Warsaw <barry at python.org>, Nick Coghlan <ncoghlan at gmail.com>
Status:
    Active
Type:
    Process
Created:
    05-Jul-2001
Post-History:
    05-Jul-2001, 01-Aug-2013
```

Comment: That makes sense thanks. Do you think I would be just annoying people if I opened an issue suggesting adding an image->Image redundancy and also moving all of the constructors on the Image module down to the Image class?

Comment: Yes, very much so: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds